# How do I export a vector .EPS in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, eps

I am saving my Inkscape .svg as an encapsulated postscript file, however the exported image is not vector. If I save as a .pdf, for example, then it is vector. The export settings are attached. Checking/unchecking the 'rasterize filter effects' box does not help, neither does the PostScrip level.

[image]

Comment: File -> Save As -> .eps?

Comment: This saves a rasterised eps, not a vector eps. I require vector

Comment: Just asking, maybe your EPS viewer is rasterizing?

Comment: I can produce eps images from other software e.g. Matlab, and these eps files are still vector. My viewer is Preview on Mac OS X.

Comment: Can you add which settings you're using to export? also perhaps a screenshot with the part of your image that doesn't convert to vector?

Comment: I use EPS export of drawings from Inkscape all the time and have never had this issue. Does your drawing have any filters or blur applied? Those can cause certain parts of your drawing to rasterize when exported. And of course, if your drawing contains an embedded raster image, it obviously won't magically become vector when exported.

Comment: Here are the eps and svg files, you can see the export settings in the main post. You may have trouble viewing the svg if you do not have computer modern (latex) fonts installed on your system. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5A18pCoosv6MFNvQVBNeThaRUk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5A18pCoosv6T1Jna3VBZ0szbGs/view?usp=sharing

Perhaps it is the transparency/ gradients causing the problems as you suggest...

Comment: Actually, I have tested this by drawing a basic shape with no filters/blur etc, and the image is still rasterized. Perhaps there is a setting elsewhere in Inkscape I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

There are certain things in and SVG drawing that will cause the EPS exporter in Inkscape to produce a rasterized version of your drawing in an EPS. There are a few things you can do to prepare your SVG to ensure that Inkscape produces a vector EPS. [Mo Duffy talks about this issue in her blogpost](http://blog.linuxgrrl.com/2013/08/12/how-to-produce-vector-eps-with-cmyk-color-using-free-software/) from a few years back, but basically, you need to:

- remove transparent gradients from your drawing. You may also need to remove all gradients.
- remove all clips and masks
- remove all inkscape patterns
- **important**: add a white, totally opaque rectangle (without a stroke) at the bottom layer of your drawing that covers just the entire page.